# Representation of xsl:value-of select

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Can anybody tell me what does the below path represent in `<xsl:value-of select >`

```
/value,'(',../../../Type,')
```

Comment: That's not a valid XPath expression. If you enter this as the value of the `select` attribute of `xsl:value-of`, you will get a compilation error.

Comment: there is no compilation error coming..

Comment: Show us a **reproducible** example.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT/XPath 2.0 the main data type is a sequence, a sequence can contain atomic values (like strings, booleans, integers, doubles, dates, dateTimes) and nodes. [On way to construct or create a sequence is to simply list its items separated by a comma](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#construct_seq), so with `<xsl:value-of select="/value,'(',../../../Type,')'"/>` the select expression is an XPath 2.0 expression constructing a sequence consisting in the node(s) selected by `/value`, the string `'('`, the node(s) selected by `../../../Type` and the string `')'`. `xsl:value-of` then outputs the string values of all items separated by a space (default) or whatever the `separator` attribute of the `xsl:value-of` defines.

Note that in your sample a closing single quote `'` seems to be missing at the end of `/value,'(',../../../Type,')` so I would expect you to get a syntax error reported by the XSLT processor.